# I cant pass variable from controller to view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I get error saying:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: views/businessinfo_view.php

My model:

```
function getPosts(){
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE 
   customer_id=12;");           
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

My controller:

```
 function ind() {
   $data['customerinfo'] = $this->user_model->getPosts(); 
   $this->load->view('businesssinfo_view', $data); 
 }
```

MY view:

```
<?php foreach($data as $d){?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $d->customer_id;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $d->first_name);?></td>
  </tr>     
<?php }?>
```

I tried 100 different ways, still can pass the variables, I know my query is correct, I can fetch and echo data in controller, I can't just pass it into view. someone please help me!

Comment: variable scope issue, $data only exists inside the function

Comment: `<?php foreach($customerinfo as $d) { ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
function controller() {   
   $data['customerinfo'] = $this->user_model->getPosts();    
   $this->load->view('businesssinfo_view', $data); 
}
```

Whenever you pass variable in view, try to access it with key inside view.
This `$customerinfo` variable will have all your data.

For EX. `$customerinfo` because your actual variable is `$data['customerinfo']`.

if var name is `$data['extraVal']`, in view access through `$extraVal`.

Comment: i have read the article about how to pass data From Controller To View In CodeIgniter 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

Try if you have the `$data['customerinfo']` then on the view you would use like `$customerinfo`

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#creating-loops

Controller

```
function ind() {
  $data['customerinfo'] = array();
  $data['customerinfo'] = $this->user_model->getPosts(); 
  $this->load->view('businesssinfo_view', $data); 
}
```

Model

```
function getPosts(){
   $this->db->where('customer_id', '12');
   $query = $this->db->get('customer');
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach($customerinfo as $d){?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $d['customer_id'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $d['first_name'];?></td>
  </tr>     
<?php }?>
```

When model function returns result_array() `<?php echo $d['first_name'];?>`

When model function returns result()  `<?php echo $d->first_name;?>`

Example found [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays)

Comment: I get same error! A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: customerinfo

Filename: views/businessinfo_view.php

Comment: Have updated it with $data['customerinfo'] = array(); on controller

Comment: public function ind() {
   $data['customerinfo'] = $this->user_model->getPosts(); // calling Post model method getPosts()
   $this->load->view('businesssinfo_view', $data['customerinfo'] = array()); // load the view file , we are passing $data array to view file
 }   is that what you said?

Comment: @Eya use `$this->load->view('businesssinfo_view', $data); ` not `$this->load->view('businesssinfo_view', $data['customerinfo'] = array()); `

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thank you for your time! but im still getting the same error! I fixed it based on your comments! but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try exactly this :

My model:

```
function getPosts(){
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE 
   customer_id = '12' ");           
   return $query->result();
}
```

My controller:

```
function ind() {
   $data['customerinfo'] = $this->user_model->getPosts(); 
   $this->load->view('businesssinfo_view', $data); 
 }
```

MY view:

```
    <?php 
if(!empty($customerinfo))
{
foreach($customerinfo as $d){?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $d->customer_id;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $d->first_name;?></td>
      </tr>     
    <?php }
}
else{
echo 'Some problem with the variable !! :(';
}
?>
```